# Getting Text from TextView nested in ListView via LongClick

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a list view which is populated with text from SQLite db according to users input via edit text. my code is:

```
Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.searchDb((query != null ? query.toString() : "@@@@"));

    if (cursor == null)
    {
    }
    else 
    {
     String[] from = new String[] 
                {
                    COLUMN-1,
                    COLUMN-2,
                    COLUMN-3
                };   
        int[] to = new int[] 
                {     
                    R.id.textView1,
                    R.id.textView2,
                    R.id.textView3
                };

            SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter1 = new      
                 simpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.searchResults, cursor, from, to);

            mListView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter1);
            registerForContextMenu(mListView);
```

and my contextmenu

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{

  AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =     
     (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
  int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
  String[] menuItems = 
    {
        "Option-1",
        "Option-2"
    };
  String menuItemName = menuItems[menuItemIndex];
  TextView textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  String text = textView4.getText();
  if(menuItemIndex == 0 )
  {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
  }

  return true;
}
```

I am trying to fetch the text of item (TextView in ListView) long clicked via string "text" in the Toast. But It always return the text of first viewable item of the list irrespective which item is clicked?  I cannot figure out where I am wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a lonfClick listener to your listView, and getting the content of the item clicked. In your case, something like:

```
yourListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {

               String text = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;
            }
        });
```

I hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me for instance. But if I implement an option menu (ContextMenu) on long click in the above case for first click on context menu it does not do anything and for subsequent clicks it directly displays the result without showing context menu (to be honest shows context menu for time being and goes to context menu click event without waiting to be clicked)

Answer (score 0):

Implement long click listener for the listview.
Try the below code. Hope it will work for you.

```
 mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,int arg2, long arg3) {
                 TextView textView4 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                  String text = textView4.getText();
                return false;
            }
        });.
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me for instance. But if I implement an option menu (ContextMenu) on long click in the above case for first click on context menu it does not do anything and for subsequent clicks it directly displays the result without showing context menu (to be honest shows context menu for time being and goes to context menu click event without waiting to be clicked)

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach inside the getView method the onClickListener. 
For instance :

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.anotherView);
    textView.setText("TEST TEXT");

    rowView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){
        public boolean onLongClick(    View v){
             // do whatever you want
             return true;
        }
    });
    return rowView;
  }
```